# JVCL installation

Tags: delphi, jvcl

I have Delphi 2007 on Windows 8.1. I have installed JCL without problems. But when I try to install JVCL I have following error:

```
JVCL 3.48.0.0


[Generating: Packages]
Generating packages for D11
    Loaded template.dpk
    Loaded template.dproj
    Loaded template.rc
[Compiling: Packages]
[Compiling: JvCore110.bpl]
CodeGear Delphi for Win32 compiler version 18.5
Copyright (c) 1983,2007 CodeGear


D:\Jvcl\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(277) Error: E2361 Cannot access private
symbol TMemIniFile.FSections
D:\Jvcl\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(277) Warning: W1023 Comparing signed
and unsigned types - widened both operands
D:\Jvcl\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(285) Error: E2361 Cannot access private
symbol TMemIniFile.FSections
D:\Jvcl\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(288) Error: E2361 Cannot access private
symbol TMemIniFile.FSections
D:\Jvcl\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(288) Error: E2029 'END' expected but
')' found
D:\Jvcl\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(291) Error: E2029 ';' expected but
'ELSE' found
D:\Jvcl\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(293) Error: E2029 '.' expected but ';'
found
JvCore.dpk(108) Fatal: F2063 Could not compile used unit
'..\..\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas'
===========================
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem today: the Andreas tip was fine!

Answer (score 5):

This compile error was fixed on 2014-05-16. You need to download a newer version.

JVCL: https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl
JCL: https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl

Comment: But I'm trying to install latest release - JVCL348CompleteJCL26-Build5178

Comment: There is no newer release so in order to get that fixed you either fix the code yourself or you use the git repository to get the newest code.